# Global variable not holding value

Tags: ms-access, vba

The Global whereAtt is not holding a value when I step into the after update method. Is there a problem with how I'm calling globals or the set up of my code?

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Dim whereAtt As String


Private Sub cmbAnalyst_AfterUpdate()

If cmbAnalyst.ListIndex <> -1 Then
    whereAtt = whereAtt & " And Analyst = 'me.cmbAnalyst'"
    Call queryBuilder
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
whereAtt = "Select * from tblActionLog where LogID is not null"
cmbAnalyst.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT Analyst FROM tblActionLog"
Call queryBuilder
End Sub

Public Sub queryBuilder()
testTable.RowSource = whereAtt
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code alters the `WHERE` clause in a `SELECT` statement like this ...

```vb
whereAtt = whereAtt & " And Analyst = 'me.cmbAnalyst'"
```

That condition will restrict rows returned by the query to only those which have the literal text string *'me.cmbAnalyst'* stored in `tblActionLog.Analyst`.

I suspect you want those rows where `tblActionLog.Analyst` matches the value selected in that `cmbAnalyst` combo box.

If that is correct, construct the string to include the combo box's value instead of its name:

```vb
whereAtt = whereAtt & " And Analyst = '" & Me.cmbAnalyst.Value & "'"
```

Regarding *"whereAtt is not holding a value when I step into the after update method"*, I don't understand what is going on there.  It looks like you would add another *"And Analyst = ... "* segment to the query each time After Update fires.  But I don't understand why the value of *whereAtt* would disappear completely.

I suggest you add `Debug.Print` statements before and after the line where you alter *whereAtt*:

```vb
Debug.Print "Before: " & whereAtt
Debug.Print "cmbAnalyst.Value: " & Me.cmbAnalyst.Value
whereAtt = whereAtt & " And Analyst = '" & Me.cmbAnalyst.Value & "'"
Debug.Print "After: " & whereAtt
```

Hopefully the situation will be clear when you view the `Debug.Print` output in the Immediate window.  If not, show us what `Debug.Print` shows you.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use:

```
Public whereAtt As String
```

To ensure a value is passed, you could also do this:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public whereAtt As String


Private Sub cmbAnalyst_AfterUpdate()
    If cmbAnalyst.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        whereAtt = whereAtt & " And Analyst = 'me.cmbAnalyst'"
        queryBuilder(whereAtt)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    whereAtt = "Select * from tblActionLog where LogID is not null"
    cmbAnalyst.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT Analyst FROM tblActionLog"
    queryBuilder(whereAtt)
End Sub

Public Sub queryBuilder(whereAtt as String)
    testTable.RowSource = whereAtt
End Sub
```